# 'Telebot' has no attribute 'types'

Tags: python, types, telegram, telegram-bot

Well, I've tried to run another's person telegram bot on my computer, but got a mistake that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dmitriy\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Main.py", line 10, in <module>
    keyboard = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
AttributeError: module 'telebot' has no attribute 'types'
```

I've tried to import types from telebot:

```
from telebot import types
```

But it didn't actually helped. The strangest thing is that this code works on code owner's computer.

What can this be about?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDY3y.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install python-telegram-bot f.e via pip

```
pip install python-telegram-bot
```

then import it from telegram package

```
from telegram import ReplyKeyboardMarkup
```

and replace creation of ReplyKeyboardMarkup into this:

```
keyboard = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
```

Comment: @domandihno , that didn't actually helped(

Comment: what error do you have after application of that chagne? Error should be different as in solution i've proposed we don't import ReplyKeyboardMarkup from telebot.types

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `telebot` and `pyTelegramBotApi` are different libraries but they are both imported via `import telebot`. In fact, when you do `from telebot import types` you import it from `pyTelegramBotApi`, not from `telebot`.

To fix the issue just type:

```
pip uninstall telebot
pip uninstall pyTelegramBotApi
pip install pyTelegramBotApi
```

It worked for me :)

Comment: Please edit the typo in the first line. `pip uninstall telebot`

Answer (score 0):

for like these errors ... reinstall the library or use (--upgrade) when you install it !

like this:

```
pip uninstall telebot
pip install pyTelegramBotAPI
pip install pytelegrambotapi --upgrade
```

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

If you use PyCharm, then I advise you to do the following.

1. Go to the directory of your project.
2. In this directory, open the venv\Scripts directory (eventually you should get the following path \venv\Scripts)
3. Next, go to the command line along this path AND ONLY AFTER THAT WRITE the pip install pyTelegramBotAPI COMMAND ♥